# are locks acquired sequentially in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Suppose we have a function that in kotlin that acquires lock and then changes a value. Something like this

```
fun changeWithLock(newValue) {
    withLock {
        value  = newValue
    }
}
```

now if this function is called twice such that the first call does not acquire lock immediately and both the function calls are waiting to acquire the lock.

```
fun changeValue() {
    changewithLock(newValue1)
    changeWithLock(newValue2)
}
```

what will be the final value of the variable `value`?

Comment: Which `withLock` method are you referring to here? The ones I know would need a `Lock` receiver or a `Mutex` receiver (in kotlinx coroutines), but that second one would also require suspend functions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 method calls are sequential here (no thread or other concurrent processing is started), so they are not in a situation where they both try to acquire the lock at the same time.

The value should consistently be `newValue2` in that case.

If the situation involved truly concurrent calls to `withLock` (on the same Lock), it could be a non-deterministic situation, but it's not the case here.